# Reseting Position in pose mode not working, AltR AltG AltS doesnt work

Tags: error, pose-mode

I think its because I saved the file without knowing the pose mode pose was all messed up. When in edit mode its normal rest position but in pose mode its mispositioned. In pose mode I select all then click AltR, AltG, AltS and it resets to a different rotation but not the correct rest pose. How can I fix this? [image: in rest position]
[image: In Pose mode after AltR/G/S]

Comment: I am running off a Mac

Comment: Alt g etc clears the transform you've given it, but in pose mode, constraints still take over.  In your case, those are your IK constraints.  From looking at the pic, the IK constraints almost certainly have their chain length set too long, but there are more problems than that.  Unfortunately, I couldn't tell you without seeing a file.